# How to exclude all vulnerabilities of hive-exec, which includes "shaded" dependency itself?

Tags: maven, security, hadoop, hive, dependencies

I must remove all "High Severity"-Vulnerabilities in "Dependency-check", which are generated through a maven-plugin. It is difficult to remove vulnerabilities of "hive-exec".

An example of result-html-file is like this.

> #### hive-exec-3.1.0.jar (shaded: org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:1.10.0)
>
> File Path: C:\Users\MYNAME\.m2\repository\org\apache\hive\hive-exec\3.1.0\
>   hive-exec-3.1.0.jar\META-INF/maven/org.apache.parquet/parquet-hadoop/pom.xml

this **"...\hive-exec-3.1.0.jar\META-INF/maven/org.apache.parquet/parquet-hadoop/pom.xml"** should be removed!

I could remove most of Vulnerabilities using < exclude > -tag in each < dependency > or changing the version.
I also tried to  exclude this "parquet-hadoop" in my pom file...

```
     <dependencies>
      ...
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
          <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
            <artifactId>parquet-hadoop-bundle</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            ...
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

But it couldn't remove this "parquet-hadoop-bundle", because they are "shaded" in the "hive-exec".

A file called **hive-exec-3.1.0.pom** inside the **hive-exec-3.1.0.jar** shades this "parquet-hadoop". The *hive-exec-3.1.0.pom* has the following contents...

```
          <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>build-exec-bundle</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>shade</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <artifactSet>
                   <includes>
                     <include>org.apache.hive:hive-common</include>
                     ...
                     <include>org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop- 
                      bundle</include>
```

I also tried to remove them with shade-plugin in my pom file. But It doesn't work.

I'll be very happy if someone has experience with this kind of problem.

Comment: POM files don't have vulnerabilities, as far as I know. Please show your own full POM

Comment: thanks for your comment. I added information to my question. hope you will still answer me.. best regards.

Answer (score 1):

A college found the solution.

```
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <classifier>core</classifier>
      <exclusions>
      ...
```

We can specify the jar of the hive-exec with the "classifier"-tag and the value-"core". This "core" includes only the essential part of the "hive-exec". In this way I could remove all high and middle vulnerabilities.